# TFTP timeout while bootstraping nodes (Mirantis Openstack)

Tags: openstack, tftp

I have a strange issue with TFTP server. While I'm trying to boot my bare-metal Dell R710 to provision new roles to Mirantis Openstack I'm getting:

```
CLIENT MAC ADDR: ....
CLIENT IP: ...
GATEWAY IP: ...
PXE-E32: TFTP open timeout
```

But the most strange thing that server will boot successfully after some time (in a few hours).
We are using integrated NICs - Broadcom NetXtream II cards
Please find below tcpdump from tftp/dhcp server (fuel master):

```
[root@fuel2 ~]# sudo tcpdump ether host d0:67:xx:xx:xx:xx
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
12:08:54.881515 IP 0.0.0.0.bootpc > 255.255.255.255.bootps: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from d0:67:xx:xx:xx:xx (oui Unknown), length 548
12:08:59.028611 IP 0.0.0.0.bootpc > 255.255.255.255.bootps: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from d0:67:xx:xx:xx:xx (oui Unknown), length 548
12:08:59.083520 ARP, Request who-has fuel2.labs.mydomain.org tell 172.25.190.7, length 46
12:08:59.083558 ARP, Reply fuel2.labs.mydomain.org is-at 00:50:56:a8:38:e1 (oui Unknown), length 28
12:08:59.083751 IP 172.25.190.7.bootpc > SI1-SCCM-LV.mydomain.org.pxe: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from d0:67:xx:xx:xx:xx (oui Unknown), length 548
12:08:59.111846 IP 172.25.190.7.ah-esp-encap > SI1-SCCM-LV.mydomain.org.tftp:  36 RRQ "boot\x86\wdsnbp.com" octet tsize 0
12:09:01.115771 IP 172.25.190.7.acp-port > SI1-SCCM-LV.mydomain.org.tftp:  36 RRQ "boot\x86\wdsnbp.com" octet tsize 0
12:09:05.125596 IP 172.25.190.7.msync > SI1-SCCM-LV.mydomain.org.tftp:  36 RRQ "boot\x86\wdsnbp.com" octet tsize 0
12:09:11.112825 IP 172.25.190.7.gxs-data-port > SI1-SCCM-LV.mydomain.org.tftp:  36 RRQ "boot\x86\wdsnbp.com" octet tsize 0
12:09:19.077381 IP 172.25.190.7.vrtl-vmf-sa > SI1-SCCM-LV.mydomain.org.tftp:  36 RRQ "boot\x86\wdsnbp.com" octet tsize 0
12:09:29.022504 IP 172.25.190.7.newlixengine > SI1-SCCM-LV.mydomain.org.tftp:  41 RRQ "boot\x86\wdsnbp.com" octet blksize 1456
12:10:05.052292 IP 172.25.190.7.newlixconfig > SI1-SCCM-LV.mydomain.org.tftp:  41 RRQ "boot\x86\wdsnbp.com" octet blksize 1456
12:11:17.063229 IP 172.25.190.7.tsrmagt > SI1-SCCM-LV.mydomain.org.tftp:  41 RRQ "boot\x86\wdsnbp.com" octet blksize 1456
12:13:05.052148 IP 172.25.190.7.tpcsrvr > SI1-SCCM-LV.mydomain.org.tftp:  41 RRQ "boot\x86\wdsnbp.com" octet blksize 1456
12:15:29.018871 IP 172.25.190.7.idware-router > SI1-SCCM-LV.mydomain.org.tftp:  41 RRQ "boot\x86\wdsnbp.com" octet blksize 1456
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was solved. Looks like we have a wds service in our network that is listening this subnet as well.